# Show the cardinality of the infinite union of sets is less than the cardinality of the Cartesian product of those sets.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ be sets such that $X_0 \neq \emptyset$ and

$$Card(X_0) < Card(X_1) < Card(X_2) < \dotsc$$

Prove that $Card(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}X_i) < Card(\prod\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}X_i)$.

My guess is to show that there exists a function $f: \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}X_i \rightarrow \prod\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}X_i$ that is injective and show that it cannot be surjective. It seems pretty clear to me though I do not know where to begin with this proof.

Comment: You seem to have an idea where to begin already: You have unfolded the definition of $<$; that's a good beginning. Now you have two separate things to prove. Choose one to prove first and work on that.

Comment: Hint for the second part: Split into cases according to whether all $X_i$ are finite. If they are, it is easy. Otherwise you can diagonalize: When $n$ is large enough you can choose $x_n\in X_n$ to be different from $f(y)_n$ for all $y\in X_k$ with $k<n$.

Comment: Do you know about König's theorem?